# Nodejs Dropbox API Make Folder and create share link with editing rights

Tags: node.js, dropbox

I checked relevant threads but did not find what I needed.
I am able to receive a link with the following sequence of API calls:

```
dbx.filesCreateFolder({ path: '/folderName' })
  .then(function(response) {
    dbx.sharingShareFolder({ path: response['path_lower'], 
                                         shared_link_policy: 'anyone',
                                         actions: ['invite_editor'],
                                         // link_settings: { access_level: 'editor' }
                           })
      .then(function(response) {
        let dropboxURL = response['preview_url'];
        // email link to users or w/e
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle share foldererror
      });
.catch(function(error) {
  // handle create folder error
});
```

I'm able to create the folder and get a URL that I can share, but the link leads the user to a page where you ask for access instead of granting full editing rights to begin with.

Hope my problem is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this issue, I managed to work around this by giving access specifically to all desired collaborators with sharingAddFolderMember.

Comment: That's the correct way to handle this. In order to grant someone access to a shared folder, you need to make them a member of the shared folder, e.g., using [`sharingAddFolderMember`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingAddFolderMember__anchor).